# error in applying flann based matcher in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am finding similarity between two images. My code is

```
img1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join("/home/atul/Documents/Data/objectdetection/imboxes1/images000.jpeg/car0.jpg"))
img2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join("/home/atul/Documents/Data/objectdetection/frames1/images000.jpeg"))
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
```

The error i am facing is-

> error Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2) error: /feedstock_root/build_artefacts/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:163:
>   error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function allocate'

How can i resolve this? Please suggest

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code please check your path as your extension is irrelevant
"/home/atul/Documents/Data/objectdetection/imboxes1/images000.jpeg/car0.jpg"
please change the images000.jpeg to simple folder images000/car0.jpg

Also check the size of query image should be smaller than that of original image